# Add a search field by header using PeopleSoft

Tags: peoplesoft

I’m looking to add search fields in each table header automatically using peoplesoft.
Example

[image]

Comment: Hi Naye, is this a peoplesoft grid? Please share more details

Comment: yes its a peoplesoft grid

Comment: Do you want to do it in a peoplesoft way or in a easy cool way?

Comment: I just want something like them example in the most feasible way possible

Comment: How familiar are you with javascript?

Comment: I have intermediate level

Answer (score 1):

Javascript solution:

1. add an html area to your page (with rec field)
2. assign via peoplecode an html object to the field
3. use something like this [Javascript Filter](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) on the table

For this to work well, your grid needs to show all rows and not paginate.

If it paginates and you need to keep the pagination, then you need to go for the PS solution:

1. Add one search field per header you want to search
2. On the fieldchange you perform a rowset flush then .Select(" WHERE ...") to populate it based on the filter